# Is there any way to receive realtime updates and have a page tab for the same facebook app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page, real-time-updates

I have a Facebook app and i want people to use the page tab feature of it which will be an iframe app specific to each page. I also need to subscribe for realtime updates from facebook for the feeds on that page. Facebook documentation has stated the both calls to be the same

```
/<page_id>/tabs
```

with the app_id to be provided. In the current case a person who does not want the page tab to be installed will be sending a delete request which will also kill the realtime updates and vice versa. Is it possible to handle both the cases with the same application. Is there an extra parameter to differentiate the requests?